# Returning promise inside loop does not stop the loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

The following method should return either a rejected **OR** a resolved promise, but it seems to return both:

```js
function isNotAlreadyRegistered(newsletterJsonArray, parsedJson){
const emailAsId = parsedJson["email"];

    newsletterJsonArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        if( entry["email"] == emailAsId){
            console.log("User already registered.");
            return Promise.reject();
        }
    });
    console.log("User not registered.")
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

The method logs both messages:

1. "User already registered."
2. "User not registered."

So in the following i can not handle the promise. Which point did i miss?

Comment: "Which point did i miss?" Returning whatever from `forEach` iteratee doesn't stop the loop. You can't stop it unless you throw an error.

Comment: `return Promise.reject();` This will return from your anonymous function `function(entry)`, not `isNotAlreadyRegistered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop `forEach` loop by returning anything. The only way to stop it is to throw an error which is NOT recommended way to do you logic.

You could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

```
function isNotAlreadyRegistered(newsletterJsonArray, parsedJson){
  const emailAsId = parsedJson.email;
  return newsletterJsonArray.some(function(entry) {
    return entry.email === emailAsId
  }) ? Promise.reject() : Promise.resolve();
}
```